# Downloading a list of images from a bucket java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, byte

Can some help me am trying to retrieve a list of images from s3 bucket below is my code but it's not compiling. `images = imageResults.toArray(images);` am getting compilation error: `Cannot resolve method 'toArray(byte[])'`,

```
 @Override
public byte[] downloadUserGalleryImages(String email) {

    UserProfile user = userRepo.findByEmail(email);
    if (Objects.isNull(user)){
        throw new UserServiceException(ErrorMessages.USER_NOT_FOUND.getErrorMessage());
    }

    String path = String.format("%s/%s/%s", BucketName.SPACE_NAME.getBucketName(),
            GALLERY_IMAGES,
            user.getUsername());
    byte[] images;
    List<byte[]> imageResults = new ArrayList<>();
    if (user.getImageGallery().size() > 0){
        user.getImageGallery().forEach(imageGallery -> {
            String imageUrl = imageGallery.getImageUrl();
            byte[] bytes = downloadUserImages(path, imageUrl);
            imageResults.add(bytes);

        });

    }
    images = new byte[imageResults.size()];
    images = imageResults.toArray(images);
    return images;
}

public byte[] downloadUserImages(String path, String key) {
    try {
        S3Object object = s3.getObject(path, key);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
    } catch (AmazonServiceException | IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to download file to s3", e);
    }
}
 tried to map Bytes to list but this returns only one image I gues it's because of flatMap
images = Bytes.toArray(imageResults.stream()
            .map(Bytes::asList)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return images;
```

I must be honest am getting struggles working with bytes so your help is highly appreciated family.

Comment: How many different images do you expect/want in this one byte array? Can you explain what `downloadUserGalleryImages` is suppose to do? I can't tell if you're trying to return the byte array of a single image or one very big byte array of multiple images (Do you handle the border where one image stops and another one begins somewhere else in your code?)

Comment: @Scratte am downloading multiple images I'll add the implementation to handle borders thanks for your comment and code below will explore and give it a try.

Comment: My Answer was focused on not getting the error, and explaining how to avoid it. I used an `ArrayList` just as a basis. You can rewrite your logic to avoid the use of the `List`, and put your `byte[]` directly into a resulting `byte[][]` using a counter. Basically looping over `user.getImageGallery().size()` instead of `imageResults.size()` in the last example. I'm not sure why you'd want the result in one large single array though. I assume it will be easier to handle downstream if the data structure is already separating the images.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle's javaDoc the method [public  T[] toArray?(T[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) of `ArrayList` expects an array of a generic type. This excludes primitives, so `byte[]` will give an error:

```java
byte[] myBytes1 = {0,1,2,3,4};
byte[] myBytes2 = {5,6,7,8,9};

List<byte[]> imageResults = new ArrayList<>();
imageResults.add(myBytes1);
imageResults.add(myBytes2);

byte[] images;
images = new byte[imageResults.size()];
images = imageResults.toArray(images); // no suitable method found for toArray(byte[])
```

Changing to `Byte[]` to give the array a "proper" type, will fix that, but the code is trying to take a list of `Byte` arrays and put those arrays into an array, which it cannot do:

```java
Byte[] myBytes1 = {0,1,2,3,4};
Byte[] myBytes2 = {5,6,7,8,9};

List<Byte[]> imageResults = new ArrayList<>();
imageResults.add(myBytes1);
imageResults.add(myBytes2);

Byte[] images;                          // This must be a Byte[], not a byte[]
images = new Byte[imageResults.size()]; 
images = imageResults.toArray(images);  // arraycopy: element type mismatch
```

It can however take a list of `byte` and put those into a `Byte` array:

```java
byte myByte1 = 1;
byte myByte2 = 2;

List<Byte> imageResults = new ArrayList<>();
imageResults.add(myByte1);
imageResults.add(myByte2);

Byte[] images;                          // This must be a Byte[], not a byte[]
images = new Byte[imageResults.size()];
images = imageResults.toArray(images);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(images));

// prints:
// [1, 2]
```

It can also take an array of `byte` and put those into a two dimensional `Byte` array. Note that they are `Byte` arrays, not `byte` arrays though, since `byte[] cannot be converted to Byte[]`:

```java
Byte[] myBytes1 = {0,1,2,3,4};
Byte[] myBytes2 = {5,6,7,8,9};

List<Byte[]> imageResults = new ArrayList<>();
imageResults.add(myBytes1);
imageResults.add(myBytes2);

Byte[][] images;
images = new Byte[imageResults.size()][];
images = imageResults.toArray(images);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(images));

// prints:
// [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

If you need a `byte[][]` and not a `Byte[][]`, you can't use the `toArray()` method. Loop the `ArrayList` instead:

```java
byte[] myBytes1 = {0,1,2,3,4};
byte[] myBytes2 = {5,6,7,8,9};

List<byte[]> imageResults = new ArrayList<>();
imageResults.add(myBytes1);
imageResults.add(myBytes2);

byte[][] images = new byte[imageResults.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < imageResults.size(); i++){
  images[i] = imageResults.get(i);
}

// alternative to the loop:
// IntStream.range(0, imageResults.size()).forEach(i -> images[i] = imageResults.get(i));

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(images));

// prints:
// [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```